# PostgreSQL with lots of LEFT JOIN-s

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a collection which can be of several types: Cat, Dog, Bird.
If it is a Cat then I need to join with Cat-related tables, same with Dog and Bird.

I end up with quite a lot of LEFT JOIN-s and when tables have lots of records the performance impacted.

```
SELECT Animal.*, CatDetail1.*, CatDetail2.*, DogDetail1.*, DogDetail2.*, BirdDetail1.*, BirdDetail2.*
FROM Animal
LEFT JOIN CatDetail1 on CatDetail1.id = Animal.id
LEFT JOIN CatDetail2 on CatDetail1.id = Animal.id
LEFT JOIN DogDetail1 on DogDetail1.id = Animal.id
LEFT JOIN DogDetail2 on DogDetail2.id = Animal.id
LEFT JOIN BirdDetail1 on BirdDetail1.id = Animal.id
LEFT JOIN BirdDetail2 on BirdDetail2.id = Animal.id
ORDER BY Animal.sequence
```

I was thinking a View might make it run faster but there is no official documentation supporting that.

Is there a way to reduce the LEFT JOIN, and use more INNER JOIN to improve performance?

[image]

Comment: If your tables are properly indexed I think you would have good performance

Comment: Not enough detail.  Ok. Bad joke.  Can you include the `CREATE TABLE` statements in the question to allow review of the design?  It's possible this tableN design can be improved.

Comment: They're not actual tables since I'm seeking conceptual solution to structural problem like this, like how people normally/usually solve this kind of lots of left-join issue.

Comment: Performance issues can be complex.  The example needs to be concrete.  In most cases, you'll have a primary key for each table, and references will be in the form of foreign keys (and constraints).  Both of these kinds of keys will (usually) have associated indexes.  But this won't always get you optimal performance.  That will depend on detail not provided by the question and more specific detail about the query to optimize.

Comment: Sounds like a server case of **premature optimization** as your are trying to optimize before actually running anything.  Being that "premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming.” (Donald Knuth, *The Art of Computer Programming*, 1968). It was true then and still is today (perhaps even more so). In this case one might question even the design.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an outer join, you cannot use an inner join. And you clearly need an outer join here.

There is no better way to write that query, and there is no substantially different way to model a situation where you want different types of objects stored in one table.

If that query is slow, that is not surprising. After all, you want everything from seven tables, and want the result sorted. If the tables are large, that will take a while.

A view won't make any difference here, since a view is just a named SQL statement, and the view name will be replaced by its definition when the query is executed.

The question you should ask yourself is if you really need everything from seven tables. Perhaps you don't need all columns? Perhaps you don't need all rows?